# Does using H1 tags for each page section create SEO problems?

Tags: seo, html, tags, heading

Some SEO articles have suggested "You should never have more than one H1 tag on a page."

Can I use H1 tags more than once? Can I use an H1 tag in each section tag or article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search engines most probably treat any `h1` element as 1st level heading, with no regard to HTML ideas about `section` elements and friends. This generally means that the rest of the content is regarded as less relevant relatively (or, if you prefer a different wording, that the content of any `h1` element is regarded as relatively more important than the rest of the content).